# Volume and surface area of a drilled out cube (BM01 2010/11 Contest Question 2)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, diophantine-equations, 3d, volume

Let $s$ be an integer greater than $6$. A solid cube of side $s$ has a square
hole of side $x < 6$ drilled directly through from one face to the opposite
face (so the drill removes a cuboid). The volume of the remaining solid
is numerically equal to the total surface area of the remaining solid.
Determine all possible integer values of $x$.

---

I've figured out the first bit, setting the equations. Would it be easier if I said "Find the solutions of $s$ and $x$ such that $s^3-x^2s=6s^2-2x^2+4xs$"? (bearing in mind that $s$ must be $>6$ and an integer and $x$ must be $<6$).

Comment: what do you mean the volume is equal to the surface area?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to make that clearer, but if you're struggling with that part, since I'm pretty sure the I've figured out the first bit, would it be easier if I said "Find the solutions of s and x such that s^3-x^2s=6s^2-2x^2+4xs" (bearing in mind that s must be >6 and an integer and x must be <6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we just need to write an equation and solve for $x$. The remaining volume is easy: It's just $s^3-sx^2$. The surface area is a little more complicated, but not too hard. We have $6s^2-2x^2$ for the outside surface area and $4sx$ for the inside surface area.

Hence we have the equation

$$s^3-sx^2=6s^2-2x^2+4sx$$

which is the same as the one you got.

Now solving the quadratic for $x$, we get

$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-4s\pm\sqrt{16s^2-4(s-2)(6s^2-s^3)}}{2(s-2)}
\\&=\frac{-4s\pm\sqrt{4s^2(4-(s-2)(6-s))}}{2(s-2)}
\\&=\frac{-2s\pm s\sqrt{4-(s-2)(6-s)}}{s-2}
\\&=\frac{-2s\pm s\sqrt{s^2-8s+16}}{s-2}
\\&=\frac{-2s\pm s(s-4)}{s-2}
\end{align}$$

Note that we can discard the negative branch because it gives a negative result for $x$. Hence
$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{-2s+ s(s-4)}{s-2}
\\&=\frac{s^2-6s}{s-2}
\\&=s-\frac{4s}{s-2}
\end{align}$$

This leaves us the problem to solve for what integers $s>6$ does $(s-2)\mid 4s$. To do this, note that $4(s-2)<4s$ and $5(s-2)=5s-10$ is greater than $4s$ whenever $s>10$, so it suffices to check the integers $s=7,8,9,10$.

Doing this we get the single solution $s=10$ which gives us $x=5$.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining?

Comment: Don't know who did the down voting, but would you mind explaining the last part to me. Why must (s-2) divide 4s, when it is not necessary for x to be an integer and this line in particular confuses me : "To do this, note that 4(s−2)<4s  and 5(s−2)=5s−10  is greater than 4s  whenever s>10 , so it suffices to check the integers s=7,8,9,10".

Comment: @MadChickenMan It is necessary for $x$ to be an integer. We have $x=$integer-fraction, which will itself be a fraction unless the original fraction is actually an integer. I will answer the second part in my next comment.

Comment: @MadChickenMan The idea is that if $s-2$ divides $4s$, then there exists some integer $k$ such that $k(s-2)=4s$. The point was that $4$ is always to small for $k$ and $5$ is too big for $k$ when $s>10$, so since there is no integer between $4$ and $5$ we know there is no solution for $s>10$, so it suffices to check $6<s\le 10$.

Comment: Woops, didn't see that x had to be an integer. Thanks for all the help. Quite a lot a laborious question though, most BMO1 questions usually aren't this hard. Do you think this is really the easiest way to do it?

Comment: @MadChickenMan It's hard to say a particular method is better than all others, but I've done enough math competition stuff to know that this is a relatively standard method of finding pairs of integer solutions to quadratics.

Comment: ...Why such downvoting? Maybe it looks like a trivial question? It's not so trivial.

Comment: I downvoted it, I can't tell you why though as I don't remember. Apologies, I removed the downvote and changed it into an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Initial area of the cube: $s^3$

Area removed: $s\cdot x^2$

Area remaining:$ s^3-sx^2$

---

Initial suface area of cube: $6s^2$

We remove $2x^2$ from the surface area but then add $4sx$ surface area. so we have surface area: $6s^2-2x^2+4sx$.

Hence we want $s^3-sx^2=6s^2-2x^2+4sx$, that is $(s-2)x^2+(4s)x+(6s^2-s^3)$. Which is a quadratic equation in $x$.

It has solutions: $x= \frac{-4 s\pm \sqrt{16 s^2-4 (s-2) (6 s^2-s^3)}}{2 (s-2)} $

---

Inspecting this function on $s$:The negative branch is negative when $s>6$ The positive branch of the function is $0$ when $s=6$ and it is an increasing function in the interval $(6,\infty)$. If you subsititute for values between $1$ and $10$ you will find that the only solution is with $s=10$ which gives $x=5$. And since it is increasing you are done.

Comment: Could you clarify the last part for me, it is unclear to me how you have determined these things. I didn't mention it in the original question, but these questions have to be answered without the aid of a calculator if that is what you have done (or it may just be my incompetence). I believe the actual solution was x=5 and s=10.

Comment: Oh I see, fixed.

Comment: @MadChickenMan no calculator is needed. Just solve a quadratic equation on $x$ (via the qudratic formula). And then evaluate the formula for the solution in ten points.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I had to give credit to the other guy, I think his solution was slightly less laborious. I'll ask you what I asked him though: do you think there is an easier way to do it that doesn't involve all this trial and error?

Comment: there is a general way to apprach the problem but you need to solve pell like equations. This method is good for an olympiad exam. you should be able to solve it in a little over thirty minutes if you realize the ideas quickly enough. leaving you more than three and a half hours to do the other two questions. The two solutions are exactly the same.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry I couldn't give credit to both answers, I did up vote your answer though.

Comment: Sure, happy to help.

Comment: @MadChickenMan (Just so you know, you can't upvote on this site until you have 15 reputation - I was the one who upvoted this answer)

Comment: Oh lol, I don't mind either way. Seriously though, it is good practice that if you find a calculation heavy, yet possible solution in an olympiad, and fail to see a simpler way quickly you get to doing the calculations.